# How to add React to a new Ruby on Rails app

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to run this command to add react to my Ruby on Rails App:

```
rails webpacker:install:react
```

the hello_react.jsx file doesn't get added automatically.

I am trying to integrate react in my rails app. But I am not managing to do it. Can anyone tell me why?

My Rails version is Rails 7.0.8

I have tried to run this command:

```
rails webpacker:install:react
```

and install the gem "react" and the gem "webpacker" and then run bundle install, but I still don't get the hello_react.jsx file.

When I try to run this command in the terminal:

```
rails webpacker:install:react
```

it says

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'webpacker:install:react' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).